# JS files 404'ing in Heroku

Tags: javascript, html, heroku

In my index.html I have the following

```
<head>

    <script src="http://getshrekt.herokuapp.com/public/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="http://getshrekt.herokuapp.com/public/io.js"> </script>
</head>
```

When I load the page, the scripts don't run and I get a 404 error in the log. I ran heroku bash and the files are in the right place. How do I fix this?

Comment: How do you upload the JS files?

Comment: They're in the public folder, along with index.html.

Comment: what is the result of `git log getshrekt/master --stat` ?

Comment: fatal: ambiguous argument 'getshrekt/master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions